# Auto Fill CheckBox as new row added - AppsScript / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code. It currently adds the checkbox to E3. I would like to modify so as a new row is added it will add a checkbox to Column E.

```
function AddCheckBox(e) {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('E3');
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
    cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put a checkbox to the column "E" on the active range.

  - In your question, you tested `spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFillToNeighbor(SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);`. From this, I thought like above.
- `a new row is added it` means that the values are put to the cells.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the active range is used.

#### Sample script:

When this script is run, a checkbox is put to the column "E" of the row of the active range.

```
function AddCheckBox(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Donations Received")  // Modified
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  var range = sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(), 5);
  range.clearContent();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the last row is used.

#### Sample script:

When this script is run, a checkbox is put to the column "E" of the last row of the active sheet.

```
function AddCheckBox(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Donations Received")  // Modified
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 5);
  range.clearContent();
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, it supposes that `AddCheckBox(e)` is installed as the installable trigger of OnEdit event trigger.

#### Sample script:

When this script is run, a checkbox is put to the column "E" of the edited row.

```
function AddCheckBox(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Donations Received") {  // Added
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
    var range = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 5);
    range.clearContent();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
  }
}
```

### Note:

- About `range.clearContent();`, if you are not required, please remove it.

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - Code works as intended - Thank you. I am trying to run the code ONLY on "Donations Received" Spreadsheet. I tried to add this but it wont run. I used              var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
sheet.setActiveSheet(sheet.getSheetByName('Donations Received'), true); What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. For your additional request, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your additional request, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike - yes again problem solved. I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tom Sawkins Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.